# Anchor tag not centered on page after clicking

Tags: jquery, anchor

I am creating a website that scrolls down to different divs by the use of anchors.  However, when I click on a link, that anchored div is not centered on the page.  I positioned my divs absolutely but I have no idea if that is affecting it?  Anyone have any clue how to get the divs centered using anchors?  Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Jean and James</title>

<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.anchor.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<link href="jj_css.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<div id="navigation" align="center">
<a href="#jeanandjames" class="anchorLink">JEAN AND JAMES</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="#feature" class="anchorLink">FEATURE PRODUCT</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="#contact" class="anchorLink">CONTACT</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

<a href="#work" class="anchorLink">WORK</a>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

<div id="logo">
<img src="logo.gif" />
</div>

<a name="jeanandjames" id="jeanandjames">
<div id="jeanandjames" align="center">
<img src="jeanandjames.jpg" /><br />
A boutique design firm specializing in hand crafted products and graphic print work.
</div>
</a>

<a name="feature" id="feature">
<div id="feature">
<img src="baby_bowtie.gif" />
</div>
</a>

<a name="contact" id="contact">
<div id="contact">
Jean & James
Chicago, IL<br /><br />

Donec faucibus nunc eget quam pretium vel porttitor diam venenatis. Nullam egestas, quam et congue rutrum, diam mauris tempus urna, eget mattis quam quam ac erat. Vivamus lobortis nunc quis arcu lobortis vel euismod felis tincidunt. Etiam facilisis, metus et mattis tempor, erat ipsum tincidunt diam, nec aliquam velit risus a lacus. Duis tempor bibendum felis, adipiscing mattis lorem eleifend fermentum. Nulla adipiscing consequat enim id sagittis. Suspendisse venenatis scelerisque orci, sed sollicitudin erat egestas in. Nunc orci leo, adipiscing vel consectetur sit amet, rutrum vitae nulla. Mauris ut mi nunc, non condimentum risus. Donec varius consequat quam vel lacinia. Etiam et eros nec quam egestas pellentesque sit amet ac nunc. 
</div>
</a>


</body>
</html>
```

And here is my css:

```
#navigation A:link {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
#navigation A:visited {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
#navigation A:active {text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
#navigation A:hover {text-decoration: none; color: #CC9;}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    z-index: 10;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
}

#logo {
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 50px;
}

#jeanandjames {
    position: absolute;
    top: 230px;
    left: 200px;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

#feature {
    position: absolute;
    top: 600px;
    left: 200px;
}

#contact {
    position: absolute;
    top: 1200px;
    left: 200px;
    width: 500px;

    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the  elements that wrap your content div's.

Answer (score 0):

I don't intend to be cruel, but both the markup and the css are bad and the question is almost as basic as "How do I center with CSS?" It's not the plug-in that's breaking things for you, it's simply your markup and CSS. Let's address a few problems:

1. All those `&nbsp;` entities are not the right way to space out your navigation. CSS is used for that.
2. You are using align="center" on a div, which defeats the purpose of CSS
3. You have a class on your anchors called "anchorLink" which is an ideal way to style those kinds of links, and yet they are not styled.
4. As a newcomer, you can be forgiven for not knowing this, but it's considered good form to create a "fiddle" (a free service at jsfiddle.net) or another hosted sample so that people can tinker instead of merely analyse code.
5. You are wrapping divs with anchor tags. I honestly can't remember if this is "incorrect" markup or simply considered bad practice.

Here's a fiddle of the markup and CSS (there's no need to include the plugin to solve your problem, so I've not bothered including it):

http://jsfiddle.net/85Tp5/

So, that's the sermon.

I'm quite willing and happy to risk being downvoted for not providing an actual answer, because I think the comments I have here are valuable ones, and it's too much to fit into an actual "comment". The other people who downvoted the question itself are in the same position as me, but didn't have the energy to write what we're all thinking.

If you really want to get some real help, use the fiddle to create an example that will work without your images. Don't worry about the scrolling plugin (it'll just jump directly to your anchor which isn't your issue at this point). Once you've got it into shape you will probably have answered your own question. But if not, people will be in a better position to help you.

All the best!